# mysql match duplicates on one column and ONLY different on another column

Tags: mysql, duplicates, unique, distinct, self-join

I have a mysql table (we'll call it 'user') with about 700,000 rows of data. Let's say here is a small sample:

```
UserID  DeptID  Name    Score
1       2       Bob     50
2       2       Bob     100
3       3       Jane    32
4       4       Jill    93
5       2       Bob     50
6       3       Jane    58
7       7       Jane    44
```

I want to show all the rows with a duplicate 'Name' AND 'DeptID', BUT ONLY different 'Score'. (UserID is irrelevant for selection, it just needs to be displayed.)

```
UserID  DeptID  Name    Score
1       2       Bob     50
2       2       Bob     100
3       3       Jane    32
6       3       Jane    58
```

So basically as you can see from above, I do **not** want to show the other Bob (UserID 5) with a Score of 50 (even though he is in Dept 2).

I have part of the query working as shown below, except it shows all the Bob's and I don't know how to get it to **only** show where the score's are **different**.

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.DeptID, A.Name, A.Score
FROM User AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Name, DeptID
    FROM User
    GROUP BY Name, DeptID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.DeptID = B.DeptID
```

This query runs within a decent amount of time. Everything else I've tried either gave incorrect results, a query error, or the query ran forever and I finally killed the process.

I know I'm missing something simple, but I'm having a hard time seeing what it is....

**EDIT** - Okay, Barmar's answer was what I was looking for, thanks! (Guess I was just staring at my SQL statement for too long, lol)

Here's a new twist though. I **only** want it to show a particular someone **if** there are 2 (or more) different scores (within the same DeptID). So for instance if there were only two Bob's that both had 50 (the 100 didn't exist), neither would be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY A.Name, A.Score` to the end so you only get one row for each combination of name and score.

And if you only want to show them if there are two different scores within the same department, use `COUNT(DISTINCT Score)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT A.UserID, A.DeptID, A.Name, A.Score
FROM User AS A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Name, DeptID
    FROM User
    GROUP BY Name, DeptID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Score) > 1
) AS B ON A.Name = B.Name AND A.DeptID = B.DeptID
GROUP BY A.Name, A.Score
```

Comment: Sounds like it needs to be `GROUP BY A.DeptID, A.Name, A.Score` from OP's description of what is desired.

Comment: That got me closer, but then I realized there is still one more step I'm trying to achieve. I edited my first post at the bottom to try and explain.

Comment: Use `COUNT(DISTINCT Score)`, I've updated the answer.